# Chapter formating, and TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I want to modify the chapter title in chapters without number (Namely, table of contents and bibliography). For this porpoise I used the following:

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
   \fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
      \large\bfseries #1
}}}
```

The problem is that now I cannot use the `\tableofcontents` command since it sends a warning stopping the compilation:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 ...umberline {1}CV D\'etaill\'e}{2}{chapter.1}

? error: unknown file type
```

It is just a warning, because by pressing enter, it continues compiling. But it is a quite annoying warning.

Any help?

Comment: It's not a warning. It is an error as you can see... What are you trying to achieve and with which document class?

Comment: I am using `report`. What I am trying to achieve (and I achieve, as soon as I do not use `\tableofcontents`), is to have the chapter title of "Table of contents", and the chapter title of "Bibliography", with the given format: enclosed in an fbox, centred, with large size and bf.

Comment: In fact, after the error, I press enter, and it continues, and everything work as expected: the titles are as I wanted, and the table of contents is correct. The only problem is the stop in the compilation each time I compile it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine it in this way (you were missing a `\par` at least, and use `\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule` instead of simply `\linewidth` to avoid bad boxes)

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
      \centering\large\bfseries #1%
}}\par\nobreak}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
   \noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
      \centering\large\bfseries #1%
}}\par\nobreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks! Then my trick with `center` works only because it adds the missing `\par`.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro You're welcome, and you're right about that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the way to solve the problem (please, if somebody can explain to me why does it works, I will be delighted). I changed the definition of `makeschapterhead` by the following:

```
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  \begin{center}
    \fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
      \large\bfseries #1
    }}
  \end{center}
}
```

That is, I just enclosed my definition in a `center` environment.

Odd.